# Does there exist a proper intermediate field between ℚ and ℚ̅ closed under taking nth roots?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, galois-theory

Title says it all. Sorry my previous question was wrong; I see now; very stupid of me. So this is what I meant to ask. I am looking for a field extension of $\mathbb Q$, let's call it $K$, s.t. $K$ is a proper subset of $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$, and $X^n-a$ has a root in $K$ whenever $a$ is in $K$.

Or is this question unknown?

Comment: The maximal Abelian extension of $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Again, this is not a question that belongs here. If you fix $n$, then can just adjoin successively $n$-th roots of some element in your field until you can't do that anymore. Any non-solvable extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ won't be contained in that field. If you don't fix $n$ you'll do it for all $n$.

Comment: @LSpice The maximal abelian extension of $\mathbb Q$ doesn't contain any cube root of $2$. Perhaps you meant the maximal solvable extension.

Comment: @Wojowu, you are [right](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/414487/does-there-exist-a-proper-intermediate-field-between-%e2%84%9a-and-%e2%84%9a%cc%85-closed-under-takin#comment1062809_414487).  I forgot about elements of fields other than $a = 1$. 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes because the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ contains all roots of all polynomials. But what we learn in elementary Galois theory is that there are polynomials that cannot be solved using any finite number of applications of the operations of taking $n$th roots for every $n$ in $\mathbb{N}$ and field operations. See for example this old post on Math Stack Exchange, where this questions might be more suited for https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/286944/quintic-polynomial-with-galois-group-a-5

Comment: thank you. Yes I was aware that the quintic has no solution formula, but I wasnt so sure whether that'd imply that there are 5th degree polynomial with roots not in the K I was looking for